# How to use a different server IP with PHP/cURL?

Tags: php, curl, ip

I have a server with different IPs assigned, how can I specifiy a different IP to be used by cURL?

Answer (score 11):

You will have to use the [`CURLOPT_INTERFACE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option:

> The name of the outgoing network
>   interface to use. This can be an
>   interface name, an IP address or a
>   host name.

It can be used in the following manner:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");`

This ofcourse, only accepts IPs and hostnames from your local machine.

Comment: Although answers like this can be found on [php.net](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), sometimes it is so much easier to find the exact answer you are looking for here, thanks @russell-dias.

Answer (score 0):

**Here quick tip**

```
$tuCurl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ip/path");
//curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain");
```

example in ubuntu

change /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://project1.local");
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/project1");
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to pass IP just to `curl_init()`? For example: `$handler = curl_init('http://some_ip_address')` and then just use this handler in options (`curl_setopt`)?

Comment: what does it do ?